# Placing and removing element on array trough object

Tags: c#

Lets assume i have 2 methods 1 that places a element on the array and one that removes it.

```
    const int Max = 10;
    int[] table= new int[Max];
```

I would like to call it up like this:

```
s1.Place(5);  // 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
s1.Place(9);  // 5 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
s1.Remove(9); // 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I would only like to use : **using system** for this.

The result i get right now when i run the program is s1 = "nameofprogram" "name of class object"
Normally i should get 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 to begin with.

Any ideas how i can exactly add or remove those elements on the array?

```
        public void Place(int g)
    {
        if (top == Max)
        {
            throw new Exception("Stack overflow...");
        }
        else
        {
            table[top] = g;
            top++;
        }
```

....

Best Regards.

EDIT:

Thanks to jon for the stringbuilder i finally get display of the values in the array.
Although i am still not able to remove any elements from the array with calling up s1.remove for example

```
    class Stack: Object
{
    private int top;
    private int Value;

    const int Max = 5;
    int[] tabel = new int[Max];

    public void Push(int g)
    {
        if (top == Max)
        {
            throw new Exception("Stack overflow...");
        }
        else
        {
            tabel[top] = g;
            top++;
        }
    }/*Push*/

    public int Pop()
    {
        return Value; //??
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (int value in tabel)
        {
            builder.Append(value);
            builder.Append(" ");
            builder.Append(top); // how to make this so it displays Top: .....value???

        }
        return builder.ToString();
    } 

}/*Stack*/
```

Above is the object class, beneath the driver where the program gets its values from.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace Stack
{
class ConsCode
{
    public void ExecuteProgram()
    {
        Console.Title = "StackDemo";
        Stack s1 = new Stack(), s2 = new Stack();
        ShowStack(s1, "s1");
        ShowStack(s2, "s2");
        Console.WriteLine();
        int getal = TryPop(s1);
        ShowStack(s1, "s1");
        TryPush(s2, 17);
        ShowStack(s2, "s2");
        TryPush(s2, -8);
        ShowStack(s2, "s2");
        TryPush(s2, 59);
        ShowStack(s2, "s2");
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            TryPush(s1, 2 * i);
            ShowStack(s1, "s1");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            TryPush(s2, i * i);
            ShowStack(s2, "s2");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            getal = TryPop(s2);
            //use number

            ShowStack(s2, "s2");
        }
    }/*ExecuteProgram*/


    private void TryPush(Stack s, int Value)
    {
        try
        {
            s.Push(Value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }/*TryPush*/

    private int TryPop(Stack s)
    {
        try
        {
            return s.Pop();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return 0;
        }
    }/*TryPop*/

    private void ShowStack(Stack s, string stackName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", stackName, s);
    }/*ShowStack*/


}/*ConsCode*/
```

}

Comment: "I would only like to use: `using system` for this."  If this is homework then you should use the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're just printing out the value of the instance of your class - if you want it to print out the contents of the array, you need to override `ToString`. For example:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (int value in table)
    {
        builder.Append(value);
        builder.Append(" ");
    }
    builder.Length--; // Remove trailing space
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to override it with something like this? (although not sure how to use it with a array, only been using this for variables itself) //public override string ToString() { return string.Format(???); }    

The string builder works and shows values in my array now though, cheers. String builder is the same as buffer in java no?

Comment: @Chris: Yes, StringBuilder is much like StringBuffer. Although in modern Java you'd use StringBuilder too :) You can't easily use a single String.Format call here because you don't want to hard-code the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You might be adding the elements to the array, but your output is wrong.  In .net, if you perform `Console.Write(myArray)`, .net will call `Array.ToString()` to get a string for the array.  By default, this will return the name of the [Array Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx).  Instead, you need to use a loop (`foreach (int i in myArray) Console.Write(i);` to output the contents.

When you have that, update your question with those details and we'll see if you still have a problem with your logic.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting `s1 = "nameofprogram" "name of class object"` is 
probably that somewhere in some code you have not shown you are outputting `s1.ToString()` or just plainly `s1` with `Console.WriteLine`.

You can override `ToString` on your class and create a string with the numbers in it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why in gods name would you want to do this?  We already have Stack and Queue implementations plus the incredible tool of Linq.  Is this for a school project?  You need to state explicitly if it is.
2. There is such a thing as a StackOverflowException already that you can use
3. I would make the Place and Remove methods extension methods on arrays.

   public static void Place(this T[] array, T obj) {
     //...
   }

Please let us know if this is part of a project before we progress any further

Comment: Yeah sorry used the proper tag now. Its part of a exercise of oop yes.
Placing elements and removing elements from a "stack".